# Compiler failed to narrow down Signal of Union type in the template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-signals

I have a union type `Animal` that unions `Cat` and `Dog` with a discriminator property `kind`:

```js
type Animal = Cat | Dog;

type Cat = {
  readonly kind: 'cat';
  readonly name: string;
};

type Dog = {
  readonly kind: 'dog';
  readonly name: string;
};
```

In my `AnimalComponent`, I have a public `animal` property of type `Signal<Animal>`.

```js
// animal.component.ts
@Component({
 ...
})
export class AnimalComponent {

  public readonly animal: Signal<Animal> = computed(() => this._buildAnimal(...));

  private _buildAnimal(...): Animal { ... }

}
```

There are two other components. The `CatComponent` accepts `Signal<Cat>` for its `@Input`. The `DogComponent` accepts `Signal<Dog>` for its `@Input`.

```js
// cat.component.ts
@Component({
  ...
})
export class CatComponent {

  @Input()
  public cat!: Signal<Cat>;

}

// dog.component.ts
@Component({
  ...
})
export class DogComponent {

  @Input()
  public dog!: Signal<Dog>;
}
```

The problem is that when I did the type narrowing on the discriminator property `kind`, the compiler failed to understand that I already check the type:

```html
// animal.component.html

<ng-container *ngIf="animal().kind === 'cat'">
  <app-cat [cat]="animal"/>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="animal().kind === 'dog'">
  <app-dog [dog]="animal"/>
</ng-container>
```

The error

```
Type 'Signal<Animal>' is not assignable to type 'Signal<Cat>. ngtsc(2322)
```

It is strange because without `Signal`, this kind of check works.

One of the solution is to use type assertion and explicitly convert to the type we want:

```js
public toCat(animal: Signal<Animal>) {
  return animal as Signal<Cat>;
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="animal().kind === 'cat'">
  <app-cat [cat]="toCat(animal)"/>
</ng-container>
```

My question is: Is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Because `animal()` is a function call, typescript won't narrow down the type to `Signal<Cat>`.

The control flow syntax should/will improve the usage of signals but it's not available yet.

Comment: Do you know when will it be available?

Comment: This will likely land in developer preview with the v17, so early november

Comment: in the mean time, you can use `$any(...)` in the templates

Comment: I am not sure using `$any(...)` is a good idea. We basically opt out of type-checking.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of not great options, both relying on **NgIf**'s **as** syntax:

1. Create a computed signal for each type that returns either the properly typed value or a undefined.
2. Create a type guard that can be used in the template.

The computed signal is the worse of the two since you have to create a signal for each, but at least it doesn't involve any type gymnastics.

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="cat() as cat"> <!-- get the signal's value -->
  <app-cat [cat]="cat"/>
</ng-container>
```

**Component Class**

```
public readonly cat = computed(() => {
  const cat = this.animal();
  return cat.kind === 'cat' ? cat : undefined;
});
```

The type guard version is probably the way to go since you don't have to create multiple signals or functions.  Maybe you can figure out the correct typings since I have to assert the proper return type.

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="asSpecifcAnimal(animal(), 'cat') as cat">
  <app-cat [cat]="cat"/>
</ng-container>
```

**Component Class**

```
asSpecifcAnimal<K extends Animal['kind'], A extends Animal, R extends A extends { kind: K } ? A : undefined>(animal: A, kind: K): R {
  // arbitrary type warning occurs if I don't assert the type as R.
  return (animal.kind === kind ? animal : undefined) as R;
}
```